# Countability of the set $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the set $(0,1)$ is uncountable from "A First Course in Analysis by Yau". I have a question about a particular step.

In the text, the result is proved by contradiction. It is supposed that the set $(0,1)$ is countable, which it is then written that there must exist a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow (0,1)$ (which is ultimately contradicted).

My question is, why does the bijective map have to exist? If we suppose that $(0,1)$ is countable, shouldn't there exist an injective map $g:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Well, if $f$ is a bijection, what is $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila meaning what is the map from $(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Meaning what kind of object is that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The preimage of $f$?

Comment: No, the inverse function, which exists since $f$ is a bijection. What is its domain and codomain?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Domain is the set $(0,1)$ and the codomain is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Are you asking me? I asked you first. Look at the definitions, and the assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe that is the correct domain and codomain of $f$. If $f$ is a bijection, then $f^{-1}$ is also a bijection.

Comment: Yes. So $f^{-1}$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ into $\Bbb N$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: It helps a lot, but I am wondering if the follow is true: Suppose you have a set $X$ that is countable. Does this mean that a bijective map $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ must exist? I just don't see how they jump from countability straight to "there is a bijective map"

Comment: Be careful as to whether "Countable" means "countably infinite" or "countable but possibly finite". If you mean "countably infinite", then yes, a bijection **must** exist between $\mathbb N$ and $X$.

Comment: If the set is infinite, is it assumed that "countable" means "countably infinite"?

Comment: Exactly. "countable" + "infinite" = "countably infinite". But some sources (they differ throughout the literature) include the concept of "finite" in "countable", while others say that "countable" means **only** "countably infinite".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is this inverse unique?

Comment: How about you figure this out yourself, using the definitions of all the objects involved?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe it is. It must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 1-1 correspondence between $A$ and $B$, if and only if a) there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ and b) at the same time there is an injection from $B$ to $A$.

So, if you can demonstrate that injection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb N$, then yes, you have demonstrated that $(0,1)$ is countable -- but more, you have proved it to be '''countably infinite'''.

Comment: So where does the bijection fit in?

Comment: It's a convenient short way to specify the definition of countability: there's an injection in both directions. So if you want to *disprove* a bijection, you just need to show that there cannot be an injection in one or other of the two directions.

Comment: If there is an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$, then that proves that the cardinality of $A$ is **at most** countably infinite. If there is an injection from $\mathbb N$ to $A$, that proves that $A$ is **at least** countably infinite. So if there is an injection **both ways**, that is, that there is a **bijection**, that proves that $A$ is **exactly** countable infinite.

Comment: Sorry, another note of confusion: "1-1 correspondence" is the same thing as "bijection", in case you didn't catch that.

Comment: Oh hahah I get you now!

Comment: feel free to upvote -- it increases your rep to upvote things.